# How do I have conditional validation for conditional inputs with react-final-form?

Tags: javascript, validation, react-final-form

I've set up some conditional fields as per https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#conditional-fields

The form is complex and uses components that are used elsewhere. These components have validators built in so they are consistent across the application. If the fields get hidden but they have a validator, the form cannot be submitted.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Please share your current approach to this problem (add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to your question).

Comment: Imagine somebody asking you "I have a problem with something complex. What's the solution please?" What do you answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair comments folks, it must've been late in the evening when I posted this.

MCVE example https://codesandbox.io/s/ymw0nvjy2j turns out to  work fine, so must be something weird I've done in my app